# Retrieve attributes of logged in LDAP user inJava

Tags: java, ldap

I am authenticating user using LDAP. After that i want to retrieve mail, username and other attributes. Is there any way to retrieve without doing search.

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://url");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "distinguished_name");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
    DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact path (DN) in the ldap server then you can do something like :

```
String dn = "uid="+ username +","+rootdn;
Attributes attrs = ctx.getAttributes(dn);
attrs.get("mail"); //gives you the mail attribute
```